# Hard use of generics in a Sorter class

Tags: java, generics

I was assigned an exercise at school: I have to define a class `ListSorter` (or `ArraySorter`) that implements many sorting algorithms we studied and uses them to sort an integer array.
I decided to try to make, instead, a generic `*Sorter<>` that could sort data of any type.
Problem is, how do you even manage arrays and generics? I've found many difficulties (couldn't even use `List.toArray()` because, if I remember well, it needs an array of the desired type to be passed, else the returned array would be `Object[]` --> `ClassCastException`).
That's why I switched to sorting arrays, hoping that it would make my work easier... it didn't.

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * The class ListSorter contains many implementations of famous sorting algorithms, whether their
 * performances are optimal or not.
 *
 */
public final class ListSorter<T extends Comparable<T>> {


/**
 * Sorts a list using the Insertion Sort algorithm, in time O(n^2). Actually, if the list is already
 * partially sorted, this method reaches better performances.
 * @param list the list to be sorted
 * @param <T> the type of the elements of the list
 */
public void insertionSort(List<T> list) {
    for (var i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        var current = list.get(i);
        int j = 0;
        // Trova il posto giusto per current
        while (j <= i - 1 && list.get(j).compareTo(current) <= 0)
            j++;
        // Scambia l'elemento corrente con l'ultimo
        list.set(i, list.get(list.size() - 1));
        // Fai posto per inserire current al posto giusto, shiftando gli elementi a destra
        for (var k = list.size() - 1; k > j; k--) {
            list.set(k, list.get(k - 1));

        }
        list.set(j, current);
    }
}

/**
 * Sorts a list using the Bubble Sort algorithm, in time O(n^2). Actually, it is far more probable
 * that this method is going to reach better performances.
 * @param list the list to be sorted
 * @param <T> the type of the elements of the list
 */
public void bubbleSort(List<T> list) {
    boolean listChanged;
    do {
        listChanged = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                var temp = list.get(i);
                list.set(i, list.get(i + 1));
                list.set(i + 1, temp);
                listChanged = true;
            }
        }
    } while (listChanged);
}

public void heapSort(List<T> list) {
    // TODO
}

public void mergeSort(T[] array) {
    mergeSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}

private void mergeSort(T[] array, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end)
        return;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    mergeSort(array, start, mid);
    mergeSort(array, mid + 1, end);
    merge(array, start, mid, end);
}

private void merge(
        T[] array, int firstPointer, int firstTerminator, int secondTerminator) {
    var auxArray = getGenericArrayInstance();
    int secondPointer = firstTerminator + 1;
    int auxPointer = 0;

    while (firstPointer <= firstTerminator && secondPointer <= secondTerminator) {
        if (array[firstPointer].compareTo(array[secondPointer]) <= 0) {
            auxArray[auxPointer] = array[firstPointer];
            firstPointer++;
        } else {
            auxArray[auxPointer] = array[secondPointer];
            secondPointer++;
        }
        auxPointer++;
    }
}

// I know this may be bad practice, but I saw it here and needed to try.
// Didn't solve my problem, though, as I can't decide the length of 
// the array --> IndexOutOfBoundsException
@SafeVarargs
private T[] getGenericArrayInstance(T ...dummyValues) {
    return dummyValues;
}
```

My question, now, is: am I trying to use generics in the wrong place, am I using the generics wrong, or what? I've never worked with them so deeply, so I would like to see what you can do in these situations.

Comment: Unfortunately, arrays and generics don't work very well together in Java (because of historical reasons / backward compatibility), so using arrays is not going to make it easier.  But what exactly is the question you want to ask? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: My question is: is there a way I can make this class work? Do I have to switch to List?

Comment: One problem is that you are calling `getGenericArrayInstance()` but you are not passing any parameters to it, so it returns an array of length 0. Should be: `var auxArray = getGenericArrayInstance(array);` instead of `var auxArray = getGenericArrayInstance();` in the `merge` method.

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted all the code, I thought I had copy-pasted only the mergeSort related ones. My problem is there, with mergeSort(). Your suggestion should solve the problem with the array of length 0, though. I'm gonna try it as soon as I can

Comment: What's the point of the `getGenericArrayInstance` method, though? It does nothing, it just returns whatever you passed to it. Note that it does not make a copy of the array (was that what you intended?).

Comment: @Jesper I think I saw this method here on SO. I wanted to use it to "instantiate" a T[], which is not possible in the common Java approach since T is a bad parameter. I don't need to copy the array, I just need another instance of a T[], to merge the two sub-sequences (too bad Merge Sort can't do _in loco_ sorting). Was there a better way I could obtain an array with the merge of these two sequences?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239903/discussion-between-thomas-herondale-and-jesper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, arrays and generics unfortunately don't work well together. The main reason for that is because arrays need runtime type information (an array knows at runtime what the type of its elements is), but generics work with type erasure (type parameters only exist at compile time). One of the consequences is that you cannot create an instance of an array of a generic type `T` with `new T[]` - the problem is that what `T` is, is unknown at runtime.

The `getGenericArrayInstance` method that you have in your question above is not a workaround for this:

```
private T[] getGenericArrayInstance(T ...dummyValues) {
    return dummyValues;
}
```

This method does nothing. It just returns the array that you pass to it. Calling it with zero arguments is just like calling it with a zero-length array, so in that case it will return a zero-length array.

There is a way to create an instance of `T[]` using reflection. But it requires you to explicitly pass the type of the elements of the array. You could write it like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

// ...

private T[] getGenericArrayInstance(Class<T> elementType, int length) {
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(elementType, length);
}
```

Note that this means you will have to pass `elementType` through the whole chain of methods as well. So you'll get:

```
public void mergeSort(T[] array, Class<T> elementType) {
    mergeSort(array, elementType, 0, array.length - 1);
}

private void mergeSort(T[] array, Class<T> elementType, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) return;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    mergeSort(array, elementType, start, mid);
    mergeSort(array, elementType, mid + 1, end);
    merge(array, elementType, start, mid, end);
}

private void merge(T[] array, Class<T> elementType, int firstPointer, int firstTerminator, int secondTerminator) {
    var auxArray = getGenericArrayInstance(elementType, array.length);

    // ...
}
```

And you'll have to call it like this:

```
String[] names = {"c", "a", "b", "z", "d"};

ListSorter<String> sorter = new ListSorter<>();

// Note that you have to pass String.class here
sorter.mergeSort(names, String.class);
```

Note: This solves the problem of creating a `T[]`. If you fix this the code still won't work, because in the `merge` method you're putting the result of the sort in `auxArray`, but you're not updating the original `array`.

(p.s.: I have a [course on Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/java-se-8-programmer-creating-using-arrays-1z0-808-cert/table-of-contents) about arrays; towards the end of the course I explain exactly what the problems are with arrays and generics).